# Kubernetes - Controller-manager and Scheduler is not listening on ports 10251-10252

Tags: kubernetes, ubuntu-20.04, bare-metal, kubeadm

I have installed kubernetes using kubeadm tool and has version 1.20.0

but it seems that the controller-manager and scheduler is not listening on 10251 and 10252 ports.
due to this prometheus is unable to etch the metrics from both of them.

I tried to use custom values file for kubeadm init and added 0.0.0.0 as addresses for both of them and it used the values, but it seems that it is still not listening and these 2 ports are still not being used on my server.

I checked for 10257 and 10259 ports but it does not gives us metrics.

kindly help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Are you sure that those two services are supposed to listen on those ports? did it work before 1.20?

Comment: yes it is listed in kubernetes documentation to open these ports, however i received an answer from the kubernetes support that these ports are depreciated and the new ports i.e. 10257 and 10259 will be used for the same but requires authentication to fetch the metrics. I guess now it is on prometheus side if they support this and is documented somewhere on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I received an answer from the kubernetes support that these ports are depreciated and the new ports i.e. 10257 and 10259 will be used for the same but requires authentication to fetch the metrics. I guess now it is on prometheus side if they support this and is documented somewhere on how to do it.